# How do I exclude onTouch method when onDoubleTapEvent is being called (in a gridview)?

Tags: android, events, double, ontouchlistener, tap

I needed a touch listener on a calendar grid view. It's supposed to have an onTouch method to get the data from dragging on the calendar, and an onDoubleTapEvent to delete entries. I also implemented the custom class MyGestureListener which extends SimpleOnGestureListener to do this. Some parts of the code can be seen below:

```
calendarGridView.setOnTouchListener(new MyGestureListener(getApplicationContext()) {
    //Touch Listener on every gridcell
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouch(v, event);
        ....
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            ....
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : {
            ....
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            ....
            }
        }
   //Save the data
   return true;
   }

   public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   .... //delete the entry, save data
   return true;
   }
```

The custom gesture listener class:

```
public class MyGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnTouchListener{

Context context;
GestureDetector gDetector;

public MyGestureListener(Context context) {
    super();

    if (gDetector == null) {
        gDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    }
    this.context = context;
}

public MyGestureListener(Context context, GestureDetector gDetector) {

    if (gDetector == null) {
        gDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    }
    this.context = context;
    this.gDetector = gDetector;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public GestureDetector getDetector() {

    return gDetector;
}
```

}

The problem here is that when I double tap on a calendar cell, it calls onDoubleTapEvent, but also the onTouch method (considering ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, and again ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP). How can I separate them?